# Create Gerrit project - with permission, unable to access it

Tags: permissions, gerrit

Question regards **Gerrit 2.14**

### Goal

I want to have projects visible only to Registered Users, and also I would wish that 'owner' of project can set it's visibility, share, hide etc *without* admin rights, or involving admin to set those rights for him/her per project. For example I want to have projects A, B, C, D, E with B, C owned by p1, and C shared between p1, p2. So user p1 would see B, C, and user p2 would see C.

### What I've checked

I believe that there are 3 ways of achieving something described above:

- user has admin rights - can set parent of project other than All-projects: *I don't want that*
- admin can set per project ACL for user/group: *I don't want that*
- user becomes Project Owner of projects s/he created

By default "Create Project" is not granted for Registered users and "READ for refs/*"

### I have tried

Setting permissions in **All-Projects.git** that all project inherit

```
Create Group
  Registered Users    
Create Project
  Registered Users

Reference: refs/*
  Allow Administrators
  Allow Project Owners
  Deny  Anonymous Users
  /* IF I add ALLOW Registered Users here -> see bottom of question */
```

and all remaining permissions unchanged, I expected to be able, as registered user:

1. Be sure that anonymous (not registered/logged on) users cannot view projects
2. Create project using both GUI and SSH
3. Be assigned as Project Owner to that project - have full control over this single project

### Result

Unfortunately, registered user can create project (if user does not select previously prepared parent `All-public-projects` - which grants multiple other permissions - default `All-projects` is assigned as parent) BUT user, who is supposed to be Project Owner cannot access this project.

### Ideas what is wrong

I'm aware that Registered Users are members of Anonymous Users group as well, but [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html) states

> Inherited access rights can be overwritten unless they are defined as BLOCK rule. BLOCK rules are used to limit the possibilities of the project owners on the inheriting projects.
>
> Changing the parent of a project is only allowed for Gerrit administrators. This means you need to contact the administrator of your Gerrit server if you want to reparent your project.

and also

> [READ] This category has a special behavior, where the per-project ACL is evaluated before the global all projects ACL. If the per-project ACL has granted Read with 'DENY', and does not otherwise grant Read with 'ALLOW', then a Read in the all projects ACL is ignored. This behavior is useful to hide a handful of projects on an otherwise public server.
>
> For an open source, public Gerrit installation it is common to grant Read to Anonymous Users in the All-Projects ACL, enabling casual browsing of any project’s changes, as well as fetching any project’s repository over SSH or HTTP. New projects can be temporarily hidden from public view by granting Read with 'DENY' to Anonymous Users and granting Read to the project owner’s group within the per-project ACL.

Now since I **do not** want to set permissions per project basis, am I correct to think that reason for this to fail is

> For the All-Projects root project any Owner access right on 'refs/*' is ignored since this permission would allow users to edit the global capabilities, which is the same as being able to administrate the Gerrit server (e.g. the user could assign the Administrate Server capability to the own account).

### Questions

If my reasoning is correct, how do I achieve my goal?

Also, granting READ refs/* to Registered User makes project to be accessible, but also all others too. How would I then be able to hide some projects from other Registered users? Or if that is not possible - how do I configure permissions in order to prevent other registered users to commit, and possibly even clone other projects?

Additional question. 
How do I quickly see who is set as project's Project Owner?

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to see not beeing the only one with such a requirement. For me everything would work just fine if the user who creates a project via Gerrit's Web UI would be automatically the project owner (only if the user is not and Admin User). However, as you know the current Web UI does neither pass this information to the Gerrit backend nor does it allow to assign project owners when creating a new project. I see the following options:

1. Open a feature request for the Gerrit dev team hoping they will consider the idea
2. Use the [create-project](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14.6/rest-api-projects.html#create-project) REST API and pass the project owner(s) for creating projects, i.e. using an own app
3. Use the [create project CLI](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14.6/cmd-create-project.html) and pass the project owner(s) for creating projects
4. Implement an own [Gerrit Plugin - see 2. Plugin Development](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14.6/index.html#_developer) which would make the current user creating a new project a project owner

For me only option 1 or 4 is viable because the other mean way too much overhead. I'm thinking about writing such a plugin, and I would make it opensource... About 2 months ago I was hoping there's aready something available I could use, but I couldn't find anything.

To your second question: I typically us the Web UI for this by going to the project's **Access** tab and then checking the who has the permission **"Owner"** for the branch **refs/***.

Comment: thanks for Your input. Regarding 1. I will check how much hassle is to simply grant all registered users Create Project global capability. Regarding second - I wasn's specific enough - I wanted to see list of all projects with their project_owners. But Your method actually doesn't work for me. For project created via ssh -> web ui "access" has only Edit button and Rights Inherit From: All-Projects entry.